# MySQL query to find related posts by tag and sort by popular?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a previous question i had read:

This is a complicated situation (for me) that I'm hopeful someone on
 here can help me with. I've done plenty of searching for a solution
 and have not been able to locate one. This is essentially my
 situation... (I've trimmed it down because if someone can help me to
 create this query I can take it from there.)

> TABLE articles (article_id, article_title)
>
> TABLE articles_tags (row_id, article_id, tag_id)
>
> TABLE article_categories (row_id, article_id, category_id)
>
> All of the tables have article_id in common. I know what all of the
>    tag_id and category_id rows are. What I want to do is return a list of
>    all the articles that article_tags and article_categories MAY have in
>    common, ordered by the number of common entries.

For example:

> article1 - tags: tag1, tag2, tag3 - categories: cat1, cat2
>
> article2 - tags: tag2 - categories: cat1, cat2
>
> article3 - tags: tag1, tag3 - categories: cat1
>
> So if my article had "tag1" and "cat1 and cat2" it should return the
>   articles in this order:
>
> article1 (tag1, cat1 and cat2 in common)
>
> article3 (tag1, cat1 in common)
>
> article2 (cat1 in common)
>
> Any help would genuinely be appreciated! Thank you!

According to this answer:

[How to Create MySQL Query to Find Related Posts from Multiple Tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497270/how-to-create-mysql-query-to-find-related-posts-from-multiple-tables/2925001#2925001)

I have use the query and it works very well:

```
SELECT article_id,count(*) AS q 
FROM article_tags 
WHERE id_tag IN (
    SELECT id_tag 
    FROM article_tags 
    WHERE article_id=41
) 
AND article_id!=41 
GROUP BY article_id 
ORDER BY q DESC
```

Now I want to sort result by article_view (there is 1 more table).

```
TABLE articles_info (article_id, article_view, article_vote, article_something)
```

Comment: So, you have a working query that does the counting for you and you want to add sorting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT at.article_id,count(*) AS q 
FROM article_tags at
INNER JOIN article_info ai ON at.article_id = ai.article_id
WHERE at.id_tag IN (
    SELECT id_tag 
    FROM article_tags 
    WHERE article_id=41
) 
AND at.article_id!=41 
GROUP BY at.article_id 
ORDER BY q DESC, ai.article_view DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I want.